# Looking for an example on how to pass file descriptors with either socket.io or IPC

Tags: node.js, sockets, unix, ipc, file-descriptor

I launch a Node.js `process A` with a terminal.

Process A launches `process B` with child_process.spawn.

In turn, `process B` launches worker processes, those are all the same type and let's call them `process(es) C`.

I want the C processes to write to the original terminal, but I want the B process to write to a log file.

In order to accomplish this, my current belief is that I have to pass the file descriptor representing the current terminal to process B using IPC or maybe socket.io.

I am looking for examples on how to pass file descriptors with IPC/socket.io but coming up empty-handed.

I really am looking for two pieces on info:

> (a) how to get a file descriptor that represents the current terminal
>   (at it's most basic those fd's are simply the integers 0,1,2 for
>   stdin,stdout, and stderr, but I don't think those will work in my
>   case).
>
> (b) I am looking for a code example on how to pass an fd with IPC in
>   Node.js. (Socket.io would work just as well, if that's possible).

Answer (score 1):

From my brief research, it looks like file descriptors are just integers, so they can be passed with JSON, like so:

```
JSON.stringify({fd: 18});
```

and you can pass this data with IPC in Node.js, or socket.io, or whatever.

Although, my research also says that just because you have an integer in hand that "represents a file descriptor", that doesn't give you much guarantees.

More info:

If you run the 'tty' command at the terminal, like so:

```
$ tty
```

you will get something like this:

> /dev/ttys001

then in Node.js, if you do

```
const fd = fs.openSync('/dev/ttys001','a');
```

then you will get the file descriptor for the tty, and that fd should be an integer.

You can use that info  to write to the tty, like so:

```
const fd = fs.openSync('/dev/ttys001','a');

const stream = fs.createWriteStream(null,{fd:fd});

process.stdout.pipe(stream);
process.stderr.pipe(stream);
```

it took me awhile to figure this out, so maybe it will help you.